# Polylang custom language switcher

Tags: wordpress, polylang, wp-nav-walker, language-switching

How to create a custom polylang language switcher like this https://prnt.sc/vnj7b3 ?
Html markup to be used :
Parent :

```
<a href="#" class="menu__link language">EN
                                <span><svg width="8px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847">
                                        <g>
                                            <path d="M225.923,354.706c-8.098,0-16.195-3.092-22.369-9.263L9.27,151.157c-12.359-12.359-12.359-32.397,0-44.751
          c12.354-12.354,32.388-12.354,44.748,0l171.905,171.915l171.906-171.909c12.359-12.354,32.391-12.354,44.744,0
          c12.365,12.354,12.365,32.392,0,44.751L248.292,345.449C242.115,351.621,234.018,354.706,225.923,354.706z" />
                                        </g>
                                    </svg></span>
                            </a>
```

Child elements that are shown in a dropdown on hover:

```
<div class="drop-block lang">
                    <a href="https://google.com" class="drop-block__link">RU</a>
                    <a href="https://google.com" class="drop-block__link">EN</a>
                    <a href="https://google.com" class="drop-block__link">UA</a>
                </div>
```

Tried this function but i have no control over the markup :

```
<?php pll_the_languages( array( 'dropdown' => 1, 'hide_current=> 1 ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get the raw data like so:

```
<?php 
// add "raw" key and save data to variable

$langs_array = pll_the_languages( array( 'dropdown' => 1, 'hide_current' => 1, 'raw' => 1 ) );

?>


<?php if ($langs_array) : ?>
  <div class="drop-block lang">
    <?php foreach ($langs_array as $lang) : ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $lang['url']; ?>" class="drop-block__link">
        <?php echo $lang['slug']; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

more info here: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

Comment: Am i doing it right ?

`<div class="drop-block lang">
       <?php $translations = pll_the_languages(array('raw' => 1)); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $translations[uk]['url']; ?>" class="drop-block__link">UA</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $translations[ru]['url']; ?>" class="drop-block__link">RU</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $translations[en]['url']; ?>" class="drop-block__link">EN</a>
                </div>`

Comment: I guess my method is more primitive ))

Comment: your way should work too, though your missing some quotes `$translations[ru]['url']` -> `$translations['ru']['url']` same for `uk`

Comment: @mikerojas sorry for the intrusion, i'm new in worpress world. Where should I add this custom code?